# Badly formatted sql query, needs cleaning up

Tags: mysql

Hey yall, I got a horrible mess of a query, was wondering if anyone could take a look at it and let me know of any suggestions of how to clean it up. It works, but it runs slowly after too many records are in there. It only involves two tables, but the query basically takes values from rows in the problem_nodes table and turns them into columns for the final result.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT urgency,
               name,
               phone,
               location,
               department,
               cc,
               status,
               case_manager,
               ip,
               case_manager_ei d,
               id_problem,
               id_problem_type,
               eid_author,
               title,
               body,
               date_created,
               date_modified
        FROM   problems AS main
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id_problem as t_urgency_id_problem,
                                  node_value AS urgency
                           FROM   problem_nodes
                           WHERE  node_name = "urgency")t_urgency
                 ON t_urgency.t_urgency_id_problem = main.id_problem
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id_problem as t_name_id_problem,
                                  node_value AS name
                           FROM   problem_nodes
                           WHERE  node_name = "name")t_name
                 ON t_name.t_name_id_problem = main.id_problem
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id_problem as t_phone_id_problem,
                                  node_value AS phone
                           FROM   problem_nodes
                           WHERE  node_name = "phone")t_phone
                 ON t_phone.t_phone_id_problem = main.id_problem
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id_problem as t_location_id_problem,
                                  node_value AS location
                           FROM   problem_nodes
                           WHERE  node_name = "location")t_location
                 ON t_location.t_location_id_problem = main.id_problem
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id_problem as t_department_id_problem,
                                  node_value AS department
                           FROM   problem_nodes
                           WHERE  node_name = "department")t_department
                 ON t_department.t_department_id_problem = main.id_problem
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id_problem as t_cc_id_problem,
                                  node_value AS cc
                           FROM   problem_nodes
                           WHERE  node_name = "cc")t_cc
                 ON t_cc.t_cc_id_problem = main.id_problem
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id_problem as t_status_id_problem,
                                  node_value AS status
                           FROM   problem_nodes
                           WHERE  node_name = "status")t_status
                 ON t_status.t_status_id_problem = main.id_problem
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id_problem as t_case_manager_id_problem,
                                  node_value AS case_manager
                           FROM   problem_nodes
                           WHERE  node_name = "case_manager")t_case_manager
                 ON t_case_manager.t_case_manager_id_problem = main.id_problem
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id_problem as t_ip_id_problem,
                                  node_value AS ip
                           FROM   problem_nodes
                           WHERE  node_name = "ip")t_ip
                 ON t_ip.t_ip_id_problem = main.id_problem
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id_problem as t_case_manager_eid_id_problem,
                                  node_value AS case_manager_eid
                           FROM   problem_nodes
                           WHERE  node_name = "case_manager_eid")
                          t_case_manager_eid
                 ON t_case_manager_eid.t_case_manager_eid_id_problem =
       main.id_problem)t
```

This pattern of retrieving data is a bit foreign to me, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your problem isn't with the formatting (how it looks), but with what it _does_ and _how_ it does it.

Comment: Weird way of Implementing Pivot ....

Comment: And also it assumes that for one Problem it will have all the problem nodes, i wonder thats always the case .... But Inner Join in query suggests the same .... And al

Comment: @Nitin Midha - It's probably not semantically a PIVOT, it looks like it's turning an EAV model into a row.

Comment: @Code Roux - Thanks, i got your point ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this `PIVOT` technique instead. I have done the first 2 cases. You should see how to extend it for the rest.

```
   SELECT main.*,
          MAX(CASE WHEN node_name = 'urgency' THEN node_value END) AS urgency,
          MAX(CASE WHEN node_name = 'name' THEN node_value END) AS name
   FROM   problems AS main INNER JOIN 
      problem_nodes pn ON pn.id_problem = main.id_problem
   WHERE node_name IN ('urgency','name')
   GROUP BY main.id_problem
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I think this was the most concise implementation, and the query is running much faster now. One more question if you don't mind. I'm now attempting to filter results by the urgency field:  
WHERE node_name IN ('urgency','name','phone','location','department','cc','status','case_manager','ip','case_manager_eid') 
   AND urgency = "whenever"

But urgency is an unknown column apparently. How would I go about resolving this?

Comment: Use `GROUP BY main.id_problem HAVING urgency=whatever` MySQL allows you to reference column aliases there.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)

The subselects are unnecessary - it can be clean up in this form:

```
SELECT t_urgency.node_value AS urgency,
       main.id_problem,
FROM problems AS main
INNER JOIN problem_nodes AS t_urgency
    ON t_urgency.id_problem = main.id_problem
    AND t_urgency.node_name = "urgency"
```

I would note that the exclusive use of INNER JOINs is a potential problem, since an attribute MUST exist in the problem_nodes table for the result set to include that row.

Answer (score 0):

The original query is basically a very unwieldy way to query an [EAV model](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAV&rct=j&q=wiki%20eav&ei=mXm4TfryG-nk0QGF4tAD&usg=AFQjCNEzzcu4ggowd04as8wme_giBi0nvg&sig2=HtGTRR71DH7K9x-b-lZi-w&cad=rja). You don't need all those JOINs. All you need is a series of correlated sub queries. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT node_value FROM problem_nodes WHERE node_name = "urgency" AND id_problem = p.id_problem ) AS t_urgency,                              
    (SELECT node_value FROM problem_nodes WHERE node_name = "name" AND id_problem = p.id_problem ) AS t_name,
    (SELECT node_value FROM problem_nodes WHERE node_name = "phone" AND id_problem = p.id_problem ) AS t_phone,
    (SELECT node_value FROM problem_nodes WHERE node_name = "location" AND id_problem = p.id_problem ) AS t_location,
    (SELECT node_value FROM problem_nodes WHERE node_name = "department" AND id_problem = p.id_problem ) AS t_department,
    (SELECT node_value FROM problem_nodes WHERE node_name = "cc" AND id_problem = p.id_problem ) AS t_cc,
    (SELECT node_value FROM problem_nodes WHERE node_name = "status" AND id_problem = p.id_problem ) AS t_status,
    (SELECT node_value FROM problem_nodes WHERE node_name = "case_manager" AND id_problem = p.id_problem ) AS t_case_manager,
    (SELECT node_value FROM problem_nodes WHERE node_name = "ip" AND id_problem = p.id_problem ) AS t_ip,
    (SELECT node_value FROM problem_nodes WHERE node_name = "case_manager_eid" AND id_problem = p.id_problem ) AS t_case_manager_eid,
    id_problem,
    id_problem_type,
    eid_author,
    title,
    body,
    date_created,
    date_modified
FROM   
    problems AS p
```

I should also mention that you might not see a performance increase if the problem_nodes.node_name column is not indexed.